# How to calculate second derivatives with pytorch autograd?

Tags: python, pytorch, physics, autograd

So I've been trying to play around with physics-informed neural networks for ODEs and PDEs.
In order to calculate the loss function one usually requires higher-order derivatives of your model with respect to the input and this is basically where my code fails.

The model is defined in the following code:

```
class pinn(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1,10),
     #nn.BatchNorm1d(10),
     #nn.ReLU(),
     nn.Linear(10,10),
     #nn.BatchNorm1d(10),
     #nn.ReLU(),
     nn.Linear(10,1)
    )
    
def forward(self,x):
    return self.net(x)
```

So a relatively simple model and in the first implementation a completely linear one...
I tried to compute the second-order derivative wrt the input x via the following code

```
x = torch.tensor([1.1],requires_grad = True)
u = model.forward(x)
print(u)

ux = torch.autograd.grad(u,x,
                            create_graph=True,
                            grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(u),
                            allow_unused = True,
                            retain_graph = True
                          )[0]

print(ux)


uxx = torch.autograd.grad(ux,x,create_graph=True,
                            grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(ux),
                            allow_unused = True,
                            retain_graph = True
                          )[0]
print(uxx)
```

However, the output is:

```
tensor([-0.0603], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)

tensor([-0.2420], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)

None
```

I assume this happens because ux is not the leaf of x, but how do I fix this?

Comment: In this particular case, the model function is linear, so the second derivative is null, right? `torch.autograd.functional.hessian(model, x)` seems to agree.
As to why it returns None rather than 0, there's an explanation here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/32304#issuecomment-580494653